# Publish error

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. 
I have a web project. Its running correctly on my local machine. I'm publishing it on the server and when I click a link which is on the Web.sitemap it is not redirecting and I see on the url:

`....com/rapor/GenericErrorPage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/rapor/CinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisi.aspx`

and the browser error is : `HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
Internet Information Services (IIS)`

myproject path on the server like this: Inetpub\t2\rapor

Comment: A couple suggestions: provide a working URL to the page that has the error. Rework your post into an answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

The correct path to your file respect the structure starting from  Inetpub/*

Considering that you haven't created a virtual directory.

So, the correct URL must be .....com/**t2**/rapor/GenericErrorPage.htm?